# Is it okay to use sources from sites without copyright?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

As I use Wiki sometimes help to establish my point, is there possibility that I can do it with sites that I can watch anime online?

Comment: I don't think that is a problem, as long as you're not promoting them.

Comment: If it is possible then You should have to write it as an answer.

Comment: Note, ALL copyright violations are only subject of law actions on behalf of copyright holder (or their representative). If the copyright owner sees their work posted online, nods and shrugs (or never learns it exists there), there is no crime. Pretty much "tree making noise falling when there's nobody to hear it" case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends.

Fansubs are considered illegal in many countries, so I doubt that'll pass.

Regarding of taking content from other sites, it depends on their ToS.

[StackExchange's license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) for instance, allows you to share and edit their content freely.

Comment: If I in advance takes the information from websites that ignored Copyright, why that would be a problem?
B.T.W, I forgot to write it also touches on not just anime manga question.

Comment: @HashiramaSenju: First, you should also take this to [mso], the general [se] meta. Second, it may cause legal problems and eventually the removal of content.

Comment: Why can't you two get along? lol

Comment: @JNat, they have a long history that's hard to overcome ;)

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: But, but, but.. He took my pet away :((

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Only because you tried to kill me with it! You were a very bad boy!